# Android XML DOM Parsing when you have namespaces?

Tags: android, xml, xml-namespaces, domparser

When you have xml nodes with namespaces like:

```
<ns:abc>
```

then

```
getElementsByTagName("abc");
```

fails, but

```
getElementsByTagName("ns:abc");
```

works. But the issue is I don't know what is the namespace prefix chosen. Also for me,

```
getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "abc");
```

and

```
getElementsByTagNameNS("http://abcnamespace.com", "abc");
```

both return null.

If device is of interest, I am using CM7 on Nook. I don't want to use SAX, any other clean way to read the node lists.

Answer (score 2):

`DocumentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true)` should fix your problem.

Comment: thanks! for the beginners: `DocumentBuilderFactory factory =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(); 
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);`