# Parsing XML of the type xlink in android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have parsed XML many times but didn't come through this type of XML to parse.

I have parsed many time XML of the type :

```
<a>
    <a1>abc</a1>
    <a2>abc</a2>
    <a3>abc</a3>
    <a4>abc</a4>
</a>
```

But I don't have any knowledge about parsing xml of the below type :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <orders>
        <order id="1" xlink:href="http://192.168.1.9/prestashop/api/orders/1"/>
        <order id="2" xlink:href="http://192.168.1.9/prestashop/api/orders/2"/>
    </orders>
</prestashop>
```

**Question** : How would I get the URL mention in side the order element..?

Comment: @LithuT.V I didn't get you.Did you ask whether i had order.id ?

Comment: Did you try something like this : http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html?
then using "public abstract Object getProperty (String name)" to get your property value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse xml with namespace using android sax parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815526/how-to-parse-xml-with-namespace-using-android-sax-parser)

Comment: @hakre Thanks..i hope that link will help me.

Comment: Search for *XML Namespaces* for the XML parser of your choice. XML Namespaces should be supported.

Comment: @hakre Yes I will try in the way you said..I know simple parsing but was unaware about parsing namespaces.

Comment: @HareshChaudhary: Please use the search before asking a question. Also collect more details, most of these common questions are already covered: [Android XML DOM Parsing when you have namespaces?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076149/android-xml-dom-parsing-when-you-have-namespaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have search things and have got the way to parse the `XMl` that i have stated above using `XMLPullParser`.

I have posted the solution here hoping it may help someone like me.

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

xpp.setInput(new StringReader (RESPONSE_STRNG_HERE));
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
{
    if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) 
    {
        System.out.println("Start document");
    } 
    else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) 
    {
        System.out.println("End document");
    } 
    else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) 
    {
        System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
        Log.e("Count ",""+xpp.getAttributeCount());
        for(int ia=0;ia<xpp.getAttributeCount();ia++)
        {
            Log.e("Attribute Name ",xpp.getAttributeName(ia));
            Log.e("Attribute Value ",xpp.getAttributeValue(ia));
        }
    } 
    else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) 
    {
        System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
    } 
    else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) 
    {
        Log.e("Text ",xpp.getText());
    }
    eventType = xpp.next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using `SaxParser` you have to subclass DefaultHandler and, inside

```
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("order")) {
                   String href = attributes.getValue("xlink:href");
            } 

    }
```

Comment: Your answer may be correct,but I am using DOM parser. :)
Still would upvote for you kind help.